# about httpd.conf

Tags: php, apache, symfony1, httpd.conf

I'm starting to learn symfony for php framework and I got problem with httpd.conf configuration.

First, I have xampplite installed on my windows c:\xampplite\

and then I created a symfony project (as described on getting started guide)
c:\xampplite\htdocs\symfonytest\

Everything works fine when I tried to access http://localhost/symfonytest/web/ 
(all icons and text are displayed pretty well)

Now I got to configure the httpd.conf and I type like this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1/symfonytest>
DocumentRoot "c:\xampplite\htdocs\symfonytest\web"
DirectoryIndex index.php
<Directory "c:\xampplite\htdocs\symfonytest\web">
AllowOverride All
Allow from All
</Directory>
    Alias /sf c:\xampplite\htdocs\symfonytest\web\sf
    <Directory "c:\xampplite\htdocs\symfonytest\web\sf">
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

But it has no effect at all ... when I type http://127.0.0.1/symfonytest/ it still displayed directory list of my c:\xampplite\htdocs\symfonytest\

How to solve this httpd.conf problem?

Thank you !!!

Comment: If you're trying to setup a name-based virtual host then I think you need to read the documentation. If you're not, then you need to explain what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I tried to "redirect" all request from http://localhost/symfonytest/ to localhost/symfonytest/web/index.php (also to hide  conf/ from the user)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that using a VirtualHost. Instead, use an Alias:

```
Alias /symphonytest/ "c:\xampplite\htdocs\symfonytest\web"

<Directory "c:\xampplite\htdocs\symfonytest\web">
AllowOverride All
Allow from All
</Directory>
Alias /sf/ c:\xampplite\htdocs\symfonytest\web\sf
<Directory "c:\xampplite\htdocs\symfonytest\web\sf">
AllowOverride All
Allow from All
</Directory>
```

This should work as you're expecting it to.